# Select data from table and SUM qty of the same ID

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sum, sql

I am trying to select the sum of a column based on the duplicate appearance of another column, here is my select:

```
SELECT  T1.GEST,T2.CODINTERN,T3.REST, SUM(T3.REST) AS Suma  
FROM mydb.t3

INNER JOIN mydb.t2 ON 
              mydb.t3.CODOBIECT = mydb.t2.CODOBIECT 
INNER JOIN mydb.1 ON 
              mydb.t3.CODNIR=mydb.t1.CODNIR 
WHERE T1.gest=738 and T3.REST>0 
GROUP BY T2.CODINTERN, T1.GEST, T3.REST;
```

And this is the output i get:

```
 CODINTERN    Gest      REST   Suma
    1005       738        58     58
    1022       738         9      9
    1066       738        25     25
    1066       738        11     11
    1068       738       283    283
```

The group by function does not seem to be working as i get the sum on each row. Any ideas on how to improve my select highly appreciated.

Expected result:

Where CODINTERN is duplicate I want to sum the REST and remove duplicate items.

```
 CODINTERN     Gest      REST   Suma
    1005       738         58     58
    1022       738          9      9
    1066       738         36     36
    1068       738        283    283
```

Comment: Post some sample data with expected result

Comment: My guess is that you should not group it by t3.rest which you are summing

Comment: @Madhivanan in output I need distinct 'CODINTERN', where CODINTERN is the same, SUM the rest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you should not group it by t3.rest which you are summing

```
SELECT  T1.GEST,T2.CODINTERN, SUM(T3.REST) AS Suma  
FROM mydb.t3

INNER JOIN mydb.t2 ON 
              mydb.t3.CODOBIECT = mydb.t2.CODOBIECT 
INNER JOIN mydb.1 ON 
              mydb.t3.CODNIR=mydb.t1.CODNIR 
WHERE T1.gest=738 and T3.REST>0 
GROUP BY T2.CODINTERN, T1.GEST;
```